# EOS MainNet local blockchain

Tags: nodeos, mainnet, blockchains

I'm trying to run a node, connected to mainnet with ability to search the whole blockchain. So that my node is connected to mainnet blockchain and gets all the new blocks, saving them to local disk. Is it possible? 
For now I use the following configuration to run the node:

```
nodeos -e -p eosio  --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --contracts-console --http-validate-host=false --genesis-json genesis.json --p2p-peer-address node1.eosnewyork.io:6987 --verbose-http-errors >> nodeos.log 2>&1 &
```

With the following `genesis.json`:

```
{
  "initial_timestamp": "2018-06-08T08:08:08.888",
  "initial_key": "EOS7EarnUhcyYqmdnPon8rm7mBCTnBoot6o7fE2WzjvEX2TdggbL3",
  "initial_configuration": {
    "max_block_net_usage": 1048576,
    "target_block_net_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_net_usage": 524288,
    "base_per_transaction_net_usage": 12,
    "net_usage_leeway": 500,
    "context_free_discount_net_usage_num": 20,
    "context_free_discount_net_usage_den": 100,
    "max_block_cpu_usage": 200000,
    "target_block_cpu_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_cpu_usage": 150000,
    "min_transaction_cpu_usage": 100,
    "max_transaction_lifetime": 3600,
    "deferred_trx_expiration_window": 600,
    "max_transaction_delay": 3888000,
    "max_inline_action_size": 4096,
    "max_inline_action_depth": 4,
    "max_authority_depth": 6
  }
}
```